# How to write multi field `in` predicate in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In JOOQ, can I write code like below SQL?

I don't know the way to write `in` predicate that have multi fields.

```sql
select some_value
  from t1
  where (t1.id1, t1.id2) in ((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1))
```

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the [`DSL.row()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) constructor. See also:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n

In your case, write:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(T1.SOME_VALUE)
   .from(T1)
   .where(row(T1.ID1, T1.ID2).in(row(1, 2), row(1, 3), row(2, 1)))
   .fetch();
```

As always:

```java
// This static import is implied
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```